# How to keep source list element in position during drag when copying into another list

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

How to keep item in the list in all time when draging item using copyArrayItem?

Here is the example code https://angular-ucjf4h.stackblitz.io

The drag item is remove from the list and added after completion. But I would like the item to stay in place.

Comment: Please share the link to editor  at stackblitz.